# What is IDE of C Language?

Tags: c, ide

I'm studying about C language and wondered about IDE of C.
We all know that we need to install JDK first If we wanna make a Java Program.

but in case of C We just need to install a Compiler (ex.Visual Studio).
do I know clear?
if so Why C doesn't need something like Java's JDK?
is it because our OS already has something to help with it?
or JDK is just a special thing for Java?

I'm sorry for my short English ..!

Comment: Some language had to be used to develop the first IDE's:)

Comment: Visual Studio is not a compiler. GCC is the compiler. IDE is Integrated development environment. IDE is a compiler and editor tools.

Comment: @MartinJames Thankyou Thankyou !! then C is the one to develop the first IDE's right? and is that why C doesn't need JDK?

Comment: A JDK is not an IDE... And C doesn't need a JDK because the J stands for Java and C is not Java...

Answer (score 2):

You need a C compiler to compile and link your C code to a native executable.  But that is all you need.

In this respect<sup>1</sup>, the difference between C and Java is that the Java compilers compile to bytecodes, not to native code.  Bytecodes are not *directly* executable.  To execute the bytecodes you need either a JDK or a JRE<sup>2</sup>.  (It is also possible to generate an executable from Java bytecodes using `jlink` for example, but that has an embedded JRE.)

The `java` executable provided by a standard JRE or JDK starts and runs a Java virtual machine (JVM).  The functionality of a JVM typicallly includes:

- a bytecode loader and verifier,
- a bytecode interpreter, and
- a Just-in-time (JIT) compiler that compiles bytecodes to platform native code ... as required.

This (e.g. the `java` command) is implemented as a native application.  Existing implementations are coded in C and C++, but that is not an absolute requirement.

You don't absolutely require an IDE for either C or Java.  Both can be developed using a simple text editor, and compiled from the command prompt.  An IDE is "nice to have" ...

---

<sup>1 - There are of course many other differences.

2 - JRE and JDK are names for the two different kinds of Java distribution.  A JRE consists of the tools and libraries for running Java applications.  A JRE *adds* development tools; e.g. compilers, packagers, debuggers and so on. (But not an IDE.)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

IDE is *Integrated Development Environment* and it is some sort of frontend or GUI for development, i.e. Eclipse (for Java and C/C++) has features like code highlighting,... IDEs are useful for more complex projects to stay on top of things. The main difference between Java and C is that Java is an *interpreted language*, it needs the JVM (Java Virtual Machine, implemented as a [stack machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine)) to run, while C is directly translated to Assembly and then [opcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode) that runs directly on the processor

*The JVM itself is written in C/C++*, the JVM generates the opcode for the processor

JAva bytecode is not understandable by the processor it is only understandable for the JVM that is then translates in to ISA opcodes (ISA -> Instruction Set Architecture)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings